# Does MySQL avoid transferring the same piece of the data over the network in an inflated query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

For example (using a simplified example to illustrate the problem), I want to display a page of comments and I also want to show the title of the entity which the comments belong to.

I can do two queries:

```
select title from entities where id = 1
select column1, column2 from comments where entity = 1
```

Or I can do one query to minimize network calls (which I prefer):

```
select title, column1, column2 from entities, comments where id = 1 and entity = id
```

In the latter case the result set is of course inflated, becase every row will have the same entity title which is needed only once.

Transferring the same thing multiple times is wasteful. Does MySQL optimize the returned data in this case and transports the title data only once over the network (and rebuilds the result set on the client)? Or does it put it in the network data as many times as many returned rows there are?

Comment: .Your second query is wrong.. you are CROSS JOINING the tables

Comment: seems that you select  few information  .. if the number of field is this you have not appreciable vantage for one query instead of  two

Comment: @scaisEdge  it's only an example to illustrate the question, in the real queries more data is selected

Comment: but the answer  depend  on the real amount of data . and frequency  .. there si not only on answer  .. depend  of the real situation .. anyway  ..  your second option is not not the valid  . one  ...  as you showed  in yoru question +

Answer (score 3):

No, MySQL does not optimize the result set by default, although this can be implemented (as Ollie points out in a comment).  It is possible that something in the various network communication layers compresses the data, but that would be unusual.

Your observation is a good observation.  Sometimes, multiple queries are more efficient, for the simple reason that less data may be passing back and forth.  Do note that the overhead for compiling and executing queries is large compared to the effort to return a few bytes of data -- so the difference in data sizes would need to be significant for the two-query method to be noticeably better.

The second query would be more properly written as:

```
select e.title, c.column1, c.column2
from entity e join
     comments c
     on e.id = c.entity
where e.id = 1 and entity = id;
```

Note the use of the explicit join, table aliases, and qualified column names.

Comment: For what it's worth, MySQL does offer a compressed client/server protocol. A MySQL client can request this with `Compress=true` in the connection string. In my experience, this ZLIB compression somewhat mitigates the traffic bloat in data duplication inherent in a large result set from a JOIN operation.

Comment: @O.Jones . . . Thank you for that information.  It is also good to know that it works across records as the OP is asking.

Comment: Normally zlib compresses text 3:1.  But, the redundancy in a resultset may yield better compression.